# I am not able to run 'dbus-launch' into Alpine Linux with Docker 23

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, dbus

This is something that worked correctly with Docker 20, but with the change to Docker 23 it keeps "thinking" infinitely and consuming CPU (i.e. freezes). I simply launch dbus in a Docker container with Alpine Linux:

```
docker run -t -i --rm alpine

apk add dbus-x11 xvfb
export DISPLAY=:99
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 800x600x24 -nolisten tcp &
dbus-launch --sh-syntax
# And here it freezes
```

I tried to add all the capabilities (`--cap-add=ALL`) to docker and boot the container with privileges (`--privileged`) but there is no way, I am not able to make it work. The funny thing is that if instead of using Alpine Linux I use Debian, it works correctly.

Can anyone come up with any ideas? Thanks in advance.